# The inside of my grill lid is rusting

Tags: equipment, grilling, propane-grill

I've seen lot's of questions in regards to the grate on a grill rusting (like this one: [Can I still cook on my propane grill with rust?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16347/can-i-still-cook-on-my-propane-grill-with-rust)) but my situation is a tad different in regards to the lid. When I rub my finger on the inside top of the grill lid, small amounts of rust particles/shavings are falling down.

I have a 5 burner Kenmore grill and the inside top of the grill lid is rusting. It appears there is actually a heat shield of sorts attached to the inside of the lid that is the part rusting. The bolts appear to be rivets or something that I can't remove. The lid is not made anymore so replacing it is out of the question. Actually the thing is only 3.5 years old and a lot of the parts aren't made which has been a frustration to this issue.

I can't remember the color and metal type of that inside lid cover shield when new but I thought it was stainless steel, however I suppose I was wrong. I'm thinking about taking the pressure washer to the inside of the lid, followed by a wire brush, repeat of the pressure washer, and then dry as a remedy. I'm assuming painting is a really bad idea because of fumes, food, etc.

Is it time to pitch the grill because of that lid rusting, or does some type of maintenance to it seem like a good idea? At the end of the day I don't want rusty burgers and steaks!

Comment: How much do you use this grill? I'm a little surprised that anything, even bare cast iron, would rust inside a grill. Mine is pretty quickly coated with cooking residue that prevents rust. Do you clean this grill really thoroughly after use?

Comment: @CareyGregory - I clean the stainless steel grate every time after cooking. I brush it and it stays almost pristine. I do not however clean the underside of the lid or under the grate where the burners are all that often.

Comment: hey @atconway how did you make out? I have the same problem on masterforge 3218 - love the grill and replaced all burners shields and drip pan recently but the lids heat shield isn't doing well - thanks.

Comment: @Tom - LOL yeah this post is 8 years old. I ended up just buying another grill. My current one has a similar issue.

Comment: @atconway thanks for the reply - I am attempting to remove the heat shield and continue use, its an expensive grill. everything is crap these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're particularly anal about the looks of the inside of your grill there may not be a solution, otherwise clean the inside as best you can and coat with an oil based cooking spray. Season the inside after spraying by bringing it up to cooking temp (about 350 degrees) without food for about an hour and let it cool. If you over heat the grill sometime during the summer or you live in a particularly corrosion prone environment you may have to repeat this at the end of the season for winter storage without rust.

Comment: I don't really care the looks, I just want it to be safe for cooking. I can season the grill as well

Answer (score 1):

Use a can of oven cleaner (see can for precautions). It will neutralise the rust somewhat, and clean off the burnt on BBQ grease

If it was stainless steel it would be a silvery colour, any other colour would be just painted steel

Rivets can be carefully drilled out, and your local steel fabricator can make a replacement piece if it's worth it? Or try it without the heat shield and see how it works

Comment: Good idea with the oven cleaner. I'll add that into the mix of cleaning.