# Plastic on grill: is my family safe?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, cleaning, propane-grill

I received an unwanted letter and, my county not allowing open-burning, I used my closed-top propane grill to burn it. After sticking it into the slots, I realized that this is imprudent, because of the plastic in the envelope (and possibly in the letter: I didn't open in, only rip it in half). The letter is now thoroughly burned, though the charred burnt paper is still in the bottom of the grill.

The only question now is how safe or unsafe is the grill? What should I do to clean the grill? Other than charred paper, there is no other visible residue.

I have read [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16347/can-i-still-cook-on-my-propane-grill-with-rust), but the linked question is about rust and concerns bacterial poisoning, not chemical.

Comment: What makes you think the envelope contains plastic?

Comment: How about throwing out the burned residues before reusing the grill? Seems like the logical step. Is there any residue stuck to the grill itself? Do you see any melted plastic?

Comment: @GdD some types of envelopes have plastic windows so you can see part of the contents, e.g. https://cdn.envelopesuperstore.com/cat-double-window-envelopes.jpg

Comment: The envelope didn't have the window thing, but it was glossy paper. I do not see any melted plastic. I have cleaned the grill and wiped out everything from the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heat the grill, like good and hot (I have used the hottest setting). Once it is hot, just scrape it down with a brush or wooden scraper. After that, let it "cook" for a few minutes. Once all that is done, I would say you are good to go.